# Cannot SSH to google cloud Linux machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh

When i attempt to SSH from https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances?authuser=0&projec

I get the error:

> Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed
>
> Code: 4010
>
> Reason: destination read failed
>
> Please ensure you can make a proper https connection to the IAP for
> TCP hostname: https://tunnel.cloudproxy.app You may be able to connect
> without using the Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy.

Though on a seperate machine i am able to login, but Firewall and other settings seem identical ?

What should i do to get in ?

Krgds.

C

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to the lack of a [firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#create-firewall-rule) to allow-ingress-from-iap with this IP range 35.235.240.0/20 that needs to be configured when using IAP (Identity-Aware Proxy).

To Allow SSH access to all VM instances in your network, do the following:

1- Open the Firewall Rules page (Navigation menu > VPC network > Firewall) and click Create firewall rule

2- Configure the following settings:

- Name: allow-ingress-from-iap
- Direction of traffic: Ingress
- Target: All instances in the network
- Source filter: IP ranges
- Source IP ranges: 35.235.240.0/20
- Protocols and ports: Select TCP and enter 22 to allow SSH

3- Click Create

Comment: I've tried, but this had no effect ? 

What is at 35.235.240.0/20 ?

Could it be something about the machine running out of disk space, which could prevent an SSH login ?

Comment: Its the IP range that is recommended to use in the documentation I shared, you need it to setup the firewall.

Comment: Here is a video that can be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1pWN3Lk7og

Comment: I couldn't make your suggestions work.

My impression is that the root casuse, was the the linux box had run out of hard disk space, causing the issues. So when i recreated the same machine, with more disk space, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that the root casuse, was the the linux box had run out of hard disk space, causing the issues.

So when i recreated the same machine, with more disk space, the issue was resolved.